# How do i move to a specific route anything which matches with abc/anything

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router

I have faced one question in React Routing Concept, Say if i have 3 components home,about and contact as about and contact. For these 3 components i have defined a path something like this abc/home(HomeComp),
abcde(aboutComp), and abc/abcd(contactComp).

How do i navigate to the specific component say HomeComp whose path matches with abc followed by anything?

Comment: this is the concept of react router that you are navigating to specific page by path.

Comment: Yeah of course it is routing concept of react but here the question is little tricky. anything which starts with abc has to move to the home component.

Comment: yeah, your (to='' and path='') should match

Comment: `<Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/abc" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/abcd" exact component={List}/>
      <Route path="/abcd/e" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact}/>`

      `<li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/abc">About</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/abc">Contact</Link></li>
                <li><Link to="/abc">List</Link></li>
`

Comment: what problem are you facing?. are you talking about nested routes?

Comment: by regular expression is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this example as you posted your question. here when you click any link then that link `to` matches with `path` like(to="/about" === path="/about")

```
const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/contact">Contact</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <hr />

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/about" component={About} />
      <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
    </div>
  </Router>
);
const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
    ....
  </div>
);
class Home extends React.Component {
  handleClick = e => {
    this.props.history.push("/about");
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Home</h2>

        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click to navigate about page</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const Contact = () => <h2>Contact</h2>;
```

[Live Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-46dw8)

Comment: Yes i have tried this and it is working fine but what if i have path="abc" , path="abcd", path="abcde" and a path which starts with abc and whatever should be moved to home component. Hope this question is clear

Comment: @AfreenKhanum no it won't because how will you seperate routes if it is having nested routes?. how your server get to know requested url?